# Using WiringPi on Azure IoT edge with VCpkg in a C module

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk, vcpkg

So this is something that is clearly above my pay grade.

I would like to create a IoT module that I can deploy to a raspberry Pi running raspbian, but I need to make use of the Azure IoT C sdk as well as wiring pi so that I can reuse a previous C program that we have built.

Now I have been struggling with this for the last 2 weeks and I cant seem to get everything lined up. I am not sure if I need to create a docker image based on raspbian so that I have easy access to the wiring pi library, but then have issues with VCpkg for the IoT sdk, or if I should go with an ubuntu based image which allows easy access to VCpkg, but then I have to somehow manually add the wiringpi library.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Could you please let us know what document you have followed for quick start so far ? We see the same question posted on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/29858/index.html)

Comment: Could you please post your workaround as Answer on this Stackoverflow forum, so that it is helpful to others as well. And we can close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a python based module, as this allowed most of the capabilities out of the box for me

The python module allowed for communication with the GPIO ports, so did not end up needing Wiring Pi. I sourced another module that covered the C++ functionality using python.